Google Map Static route DRIVING with no road itinerary
Can we create a directionsService.route() when there is no connection road between two waypoints ?
For example with this itinerary : https://www.google.com/maps/dir/New+York,+NY,+USA/Miami,+FL,+USA/Paris,+France/
Adding :
this one : https://www.google.com/maps/dir/New+York,+NY,+USA/Miami,+FL,+USA/
and this other one : https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Miami,+FL,+USA/Paris,+France/
I tried to code a JS for that, it works with road itineraries but doesn't send any response if there is no road connections

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can try it there : https://jsfiddle.net/Pierronimo/bgu26o4a/7/
If you select "Montreal" as waypoint, it works because there are roads connecting everything.
But if you select "Paris" as waypoint, there is no itinerary.
I would like to have a complete itinerary including road itinerary if there is, and flight or just a line if there is no road itinerary
